# capture % number or none keyword using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to capture color syntax which can be either in number % or *none* keyword as per [CSS specifications.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#missing)

below is my regex which capture number% but not able to capture `none` keyword

```
((?:rgba?|hsla?|hwb|(ok)?lab|(ok)?lch)\((:?-?[\d.]+%?(deg|rad|grad|turn)?[,\s]+){2,3}[\s/]*-?[\d.]+%?\))
```

but when we use *none* keyword in syntax it did not capture.

```js
const str = `{  
    rgb(102 none none / none);
    rgba(40%, 20%, 60%, 100%);
    hsl(270deg none none);
    hsla(270deg none none 100);
    hwb(0.75turn 20 40));
    hwb(none 20% 40%);
    lch(32.39 61.25 none)
    oklch(0.44 0.16 303.38)
    lab(32.39 38.43 -47.69 / 1)
    oklab(44% 0.09 -0.13)
    hwb(0.75turn 20% 40%);
    rgba(40%, 20%, 60%, 100%);
    hwb(4.712rad 20% 40%);
}`;

const ptrn = `((?:rgba?|hsla?|hwb|(ok)?lab|(ok)?lch)\\((:?-?[\\d\.]+%?(deg|rad|grad|turn)?[,\\s]+){2,3}[\\s/]*-?[\\d\.]+%?\\))`;

const rgx = new RegExp(ptrn, 'mig');

const matches = str.matchAll(rgx);

[...matches].forEach( m => {
 console.log(m[1]);
})
```

How to include this in the regex ?

[working example](https://regexr.com/7c5fo)

Comment: Dou you really need to check for all those units inside parentheses? Maybe [something simple](https://regex101.com/r/fof7E9/2) would suffice. This one checks just for the prefix and if there is at least one digit inside the parentheses.

Comment: this is good approach. will try but we need only 3 or 4 places if nore than that then not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make an alternate pattern for the numeric parts. I would also allow for more white space:

```js
const str = `{  
    rgb(102 none none / none);
    rgba(40%, 20%, 60%, 100%);
    hsl(270deg none none);
    hsla(270deg none none 100);
    hwb(0.75turn 20 40));
    hwb(none 20% 40%);
    lch(32.39 61.25 none)
    oklch(0.44 0.16 303.38)
    lab(32.39 38.43 -47.69 / 1)
    oklab(44% 0.09 -0.13)
    hwb(0.75turn 20% 40%);
    rgba(40%, 20%, 60%, 100%);
    hwb(4.712rad 20% 40%);
}`;

const ptrn = `((?:rgba?|hsla?|hwb|(ok)?lab|(ok)?lch)\\s*\\(\\s*(:?(-?[\\d\.]+%?(deg|rad|grad|turn)?|none)[,\\s]+){2,3}[\\s/]*(-?[\\d\.]+%?|none)\\s*\\))`;

const rgx = new RegExp(ptrn, 'mig');

const matches = str.matchAll(rgx);

[...matches].forEach( m => {
 console.log(m[1]);
})
```